# Trying to use jQuery on my Nokia gives me this error: TypeError: "Object $ (result of expression $) does not allow calls."

Tags: jquery, webkit, symbian, nokia, s60

[image: Nokia Error][flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/diesel_travis/4859762987/)

Here's a simplified demo: http://jsbin.com/emugo3

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
try {
  $(function () {
    $.noop();
    $("#hello").text("it works");
  });
} catch (e) {
  alert(e.message);
}
</script>
```

The user agent for my phone's browser is:

```
NokiaE71x/ATT.03.28 Mozilla/5.0 SymbianOS/9.3; U; [en]; Series60/3.2; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 AppleWebKit/413 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/413
```

I've tried googling this error and I've seen people with really old versions of Safari having the same issue, but I haven't seen a solution yet. Does anyone know anything I can try?

Comment: Why are you calling `$.noop()`?

Comment: I'm just using it as a simplified test case.

Comment: The short answer is that jQuery doesn't support that browser...because it doesn't support JavaScript correctly, jQuery's working on a mobile version, but it'll be some time before it's ready.

Comment: @Nick Craver - that browser is given a 'B' on this chart: 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/jeresig/4856164805/ 

So I'm guessing that someone, somewhere got at least the basic function working.

Comment: Read more about that chart: http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/ That's what they *want* to support, it's a rating of the browser and it's abilities, not how well jQuery currently runs in it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is to use version 1.2.6 of jQuery:
http://jsbin.com/emugo3/14

That was the latest version that still works with my phone.